# React Native best recommended Frameworks or folder structure best practice

Tags: react-native, frameworks, directory-structure

I'm starting on new react native project. But I have not found anything on official website regarding folder structure. Can someone point out the right way to structure a project.

Also, If there are any frameworks available, please suggest. It would be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, as far as I know, the is no official recommendation concerning this case. I prefer to structure it as follows (you should adjust it as required, there isn't really a "right way"):

- **components**: Higher order components *(e.g. Signin, LoginForm...)*

  - **common**: Reusable [dumb](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/dumb-components-and-smart-components-e7b33a698d43) components *(e.g. custom Button)*. You can also use established UI-Kits like [react native elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements), [shoutem](https://github.com/shoutem/ui) or [react native material ui](https://github.com/xotahal/react-native-material-ui)
- **containers**: [Container](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) to connect dumb components to redux store.
- **redux**: Good [tutorial](https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux-6cd4addeb29) here.

  - **actions**
  - **store**

    - **reducers**
- **constants**
- **config**
- **assets**: *(e.g. Images, [Animation files](https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native) etc.)*
- *App.js*: Entry point
- *Router.js*: Contains routing transitions and [navigation](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) conf. etc.

---

Other libraries I prefer to use:

- Flow for typechecking
- react-native-animatable for different animations
- redux-logger and redux-thunk (logging & async actions)
- react-native-typography (standardize text stylings)
- react-native-vector-icons